# Wrong spacing around guillemets

Tags: spacing, unicode, french

I use UTF-8 encoding to type a document in French, with the following definitions for guillemets:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{AB}{\og}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{BB}{\fg\xspace}
```

and the Babel package:

```
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
```

However, when I type a text like `ceci cela «~quoted~» ceci cela`, the spacing is wrong around the opening guillemet:

[image]

Notice that the space before the opening guillemet is too small, and the spacing after is too large. The closing guillemet has correct spacing. How could I fix that?

Comment: I remember sending a bug report to the (active) developer of the french `babel` package earlier this year, regarding this particular issue when using XeLaTeX. He issued a corrective patch within days, which is available for download [here](http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/frenchb/). (Note: I am unsure whether it solves your problem, but someone might be interested in this anyway.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The spacing is already inserted by `\og` and `\fg`, so you shouldn't type the `~`. You can consider changing the definition of the Unicode character as

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{AB}{\og\ignorespaces}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{BB}{\unskip\fg}
```

so that inputting

```
Ces simulations «directes» sont ainsi

Ces simulations « directes » sont ainsi
```

will be equivalent.

[image]

Notice that `\xspace` does nothing.

If you insist to type `«~directes~»`, then the definition for the open guillemets character could be

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{AB}{%
  \og\@ifnextchar~{\@gobble}{}}
\makeatother
```

<sub>Say what you want, but I find this spacing awful. `;-)`</sub>

Comment: The reason I type the space is that I am so used to it in all other environments that I cannot refrain from typing it when I write in TeX… And if I continue typing the `~`, `\ignorespaces` isn't enough, I still get wrong spacing.

Comment: @F'x With that definition just don't use `~`. Since you probably use the `T1` encoding, you can also write `<<~directes~>>` but with a slight difference in spacing (`\og` and `\fg` are designed for removing the little space in excess).

Comment: I understand, but not using `~` isn't a solution for me. I'm sure LaTeX has a way of accomodating my particular need, rather than me having to do the extra work

Comment: @F'x  I've added an alternative definition that allows `«~`.