# How to fit parentheses (Guillemets) into a single line in LaTeX

Tags: typography, brackets, french, letterspacing

I'm looking for a way to process parentheses so that they don't come at the end or beginning of a line.

The typography of parentheses in French (« ») doesn't like to isolate either of the parentheses across a line.
I've explored several ways to adjust them on the same line, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

In this image, the isolated parentheses are marked in red.

I could really benefit from your expertise.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\begin{document}
« Lorem » « ipsum » « dolor » « sit » « amet », « consectetur » « adipiscing » « elit ». « Duis » « aliquam » « laoreet » « consequat ». « Donec » « commodo » « nibh » « sit » « amet » « massa » « aliquet », « eget » « interdum » « est » « blandit ». « Aliquam in accumsan ipsum ». Aliquam in accumsam ipsum « Donec nec massa vitae metus fringilla lobortis vel vitae neque ». « Praesent quis justo sit amet enim maximus egestas id eu ante ». « Sed est leo », « facilisis vel diam sit amet », « convallis gravida nunc ». « Donec vitae lectus lorem ». « Suspendisse suscipit eros turpis », « in venenatis dolor posuere sit amet ». « Duis facilisis velit in nibh interdum sagittis ». « Maecenas tempus risus ac sapien rhoncus consequat ». « Fusce » « convallis » « arcu » « hendrerit » « mauris » « dictum » « tempor ».
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71035 ?

Answer (score 3):

babel-french has an option for this. Check in the documentation (available with `texdoc babel-french`) the section about "Guillemets" for more options.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchsetup{og=«, fg=»} %guillemets
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}


« Lorem » « ipsum » « dolor » « sit » « amet », « consectetur » « adipiscing » « elit ». « Duis » « aliquam » « laoreet » « consequat ». « Donec » « commodo » « nibh » « sit » « amet » « massa » « aliquet », « eget » « interdum » « est » « blandit ». « Aliquam in accumsan ipsum ». Aliquam in accumsam ipsum « Donec nec massa vitae metus fringilla lobortis vel vitae neque ». « Praesent quis justo sit amet enim maximus egestas id eu ante ». « Sed est leo », « facilisis vel diam sit amet », « convallis gravida nunc ». « Donec vitae lectus lorem ». « Suspendisse suscipit eros turpis », « in venenatis dolor posuere sit amet ». « Duis facilisis velit in nibh interdum sagittis ». « Maecenas tempus risus ac sapien rhoncus consequat ». « Fusce » « convallis » « arcu » « hendrerit » « mauris » « dictum » « tempor ».

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 The documentation is named [frenchb.pdf](https://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/french/frenchb.pdf)